# Excel VBA: Use UserForm to Select which Macros to Run

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, userform

I really need help for this simple problem.

I have one big macro that automatically creates a powerpoint from a standard excel file. The beginning of the macro looks like this:

```
Sub MyMacro()

Call Part 1

Call Part 2

Call Part 3

End Sub
```

Each "Part"-Sub creates a different part of the powerpoint presentation. Now I made a userForm that has 3 checkboxes (Part1,Part2,Part3) and want the user to be able to check whichever box he wants to get the parts of the powerpoint that he needs created. How can I achieve this?

Thank you so much in advance.

Imgur Folder with Images for futher Clarification:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMAG6.jpg

THANK YOU SO MUCH IN ADVANCE!!

Comment: Welcome to SO! What about `If Part1.Value Then Call Part 1` for each call in your `MyMacro()`?

Comment: And this would go into the UserForm Code right? How would I first make all the choices and then have them all run with the "Create  PowerPoint" Button in the UserForm? Sorry I am a VBA noob but thanks so much for your quick reply!

Comment: No, you will place these checks before each call in the PowerPoint presentation generation routine - while the userform is in memory, its flag values ​​will be available in the module routine. You can specify the name of the checkbox using the form name myUserForm.Part1.Value

Comment: Before I saw your last comment I started working with the Info from your 1st comment and now I got it to work. In case you're interested, I did it like this:
In the UserForm "Start PowerPoint" button I have this for each part of the PP:

If Part1.Value Then
Call Module.Part1
End If

So thank you so much for your help, it works perfectly! Even though I didnt do it as you intended :P